# how to use ant-contrib tasks in eclipse auto content assist

Tags: eclipse, ant, content-assist, ant-contrib

I have Eclipse Ganymede and would like to use the auto content assist feature for `ant`. I have the `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` with me.

What configuration is required in eclipse to use auto content assist which can include tasks for `ant-contrib` as well?

When I use the following the `ant` can recognize tasks for ant-contrib but content assist doesn't work?

```
<!-- Define classpath for ant-contrib tasks -->
<path id="ant.contrib.classpath">
    <fileset dir="/path/to/lib/">
        <include name="ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Task definition -->
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath refid="ant.contrib.classpath" />
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following.

I understand that for Ant 1.6 and later you need to reference the antcontrib XML file instead of the properties file like so :

```
<!-- Task definition -->
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath refid="ant.contrib.classpath" />
</taskdef>
```

This is also detailed **[here](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html)**.

Besides that, in `Preferences -> Ant -> Editor -> Content Assist` check that `Provide proposals for user defined tasks` is checked like so (this is also the default) :

[image]

If both of the above are in place you should get the content assist as shown here (This is the code from your post, the only difference being, that have replaced the reference to `antcontrib.properties` with `antlib.xml`) :

[image]

Replacing the reference to the properties file with the xml one made all the difference for me on Eclipse Indigo SR2 (64 Bit).

I checked to make sure that this feature ( Content assist for user-defined ant tasks) is available *at least* since Eclipse 3.3. There were performance problems in the Ant Editor related specifically to this feature in Eclipse 3.3 but the same have since been resolved.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. If I write `if` or `var` no `content-assist` shows up.

Comment: Then must have something to do with your Eclipse version. I assume when you say that nothing shows up, you mean even after using the XML file ? Try this in a new workspace. What happens if you try this with Eclipse Indigo SR2 ?

Comment: Works well (even with content assist) on the newest Eclipse Kepler and Ubuntu 13.04 - firstly I installed `ant-contrib` package (`sudo apt-get install ant-contrib`) than added installed jar into the classpath in Eclipse's preferences dialog (`/user/share/java/ant-contrib.jar`) and in build files I'm using only `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>`.