# Ant-Contrib content assist in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, ant-contrib

I am working with some `ANT` build scripts in `eclipse`.

I have just recently installed eclipse 4.2.

When i was using an older version of eclipse the content assist for `ANT-contrib` stuff was working. Now with 4.2 it is not working.

I was wondering how to get content assist working in eclipse for ant-contrib.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857906/how-to-use-ant-contrib-tasks-in-eclipse-auto-content-assist) says you need to reference the ant-contrib tasks in a certain way in your own Ant file and to activate a certain preference in the Eclipse settings.

Comment: You can also avoid the classpath setup if you don't mind adding ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar to the Global Entries portion of the Ant classpath in Eclipse (Windows > Preferences > Ant > Runtime).

Comment: This did not work with eclipse 4.2. At least it is not working for me. I already have that stuff in my ant file. It was working fine in the 3 series of eclipse. But now that i switched to 4.2 it no longer works.